# Cannot insert a image in Tkinter Label even after anchoring it

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgtB.jpg) Here is my code

I've attached a link of well formatted code image and file

```
import os. 
from Tkinter import *.     
root=Tk().   
m=Label(root,text="Processing...",fg="bue",font="calibri 35 bold"). 
os.chdir("f:\\").            
im=PhotoImage("MM.jpg")    
ok=Toplevel(root)    
s=Label(root,text="Img",image=im)   
s.photo=im

s.image=im 

s.grid(row=0,column=0) m.grid(row=1,column=0)
but=None.  
def dat():.     
    global s,root,but.      
    s.destroy().      
    m.destroy(). 
    but=Label(root,text="Done").  
    but.pack().
    root.overrideredirect(False). 

root.mainloop().
```

I've attached a image of properly indented code in the link
or my file's drive link
[Drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9I-PRK8gXBeSlJaM3gyWkJiaWc)

Comment: You need to fix the formatting of your code, unless you do really have your whole program on a single line.

Comment: indentation is _critical_ when posting python code.

Comment: It every time complains indentation Indentation is not done properly so I need to put the link to it

Comment: Take your properly formatted code that you actually have now on your system. Paste it into the question. Highlight all of the code. Click the button that looks like `{}`. That's all you have to do. Or just spend two minutes to manually indent each line. There's only a dozen or so lines, it can't be that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reformat your code so that you can get better help and quickly.

Meanwhile I have a code below showing you how to properly open a .jpg file  and have it appear in a tk.Label. I hope this basics can guide you to solve your code problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  #added

root=Tk() 

filename = "minion.jpg" # Put your filename (can also use full path)here
im = Image.open(filename) #added
im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im) #revised

s=Label(root,text="Img",image=im) 
s.grid(row=0,column=0)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

**Update:**
I have added the image commands into your script. Do note, your code contained several wrong indents, which pycharm highlighted to me. There were typos, wrong placement of certain commands and missing import statement. I took the liberty to correct them sufficient enough for tkinter to generate a tk window with your label and image, so to be able to answer your question. A screen shot of pycharm with python2.7, a revised code and tk window with label and image is attached below.

Note: For .jpg image you need the PIL or Pillow modules installed to open such file type. Do make sure you have that. If you don't have, follow the instructions in this [webpage](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/installation.html#basic-installation) to install it. That is the limitation of the PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage method. You can read more from this [website](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html).

[image: result]

Comment: Image yet not visible

Comment: @Anonymous What environment r u running this code in? What error do you get? Pls remember to tidy up your code in the question and reflect the error messages you have.

Comment: I'm running it in python2.7 in pycharm

Comment: Your code works fine but is there a problem with default tk.photoimage

Comment: Thanks for all your replies

Comment: If it works kindly click answered (i.e. click the tick on the top left of my answer) . Clicking the up arrow indicates the answer is helpful. You can click on both tick and up-arrow if you like. Thanks.